# Pairing a Bluetooth headset with Windows PC

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I was wondering if it's possible to pair my Bluetooth headset (i.Tech Arrow 2) with my Windows 7, so that I can use it in Skype, for instance?

Windows recognizes it, but it fails to find drivers for it, and I can't seem to find any drivers for it on their website.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

I forgot to mention that my computer is Lenovo S10e, which has a Broadcom Bluetooth adapter.

Windows 7 kept suggesting that I should update my Bluetooth drivers from the Broadcom website, but that didn't work - the installation couldn't find my adapter.

I stumbled upon a thread on the Lenovo S10 forums where it was suggested that I install the Broadcom Bluetooth driver for Vista. I downloaded the drivers from [this thread](http://s10lenovo.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2467), and before installing, I disabled the default Bluetooth drivers in control panel.

After installing, I tried pairing the headset again - not only it was recognized - I also got a wizard dialog asking me if I want to use the headset with Skype! So after about 2 clicks it was working. I was asked to allow BTStackServer in Skype, but that was all!

Answer (score 2):

I got this working today using the default drivers and my Broadcom bluetooth adapter (branded IOGear)

windows 7 could install drivers for it, but it would ask for drivers for every device, and wasn't able to actually use any of them.

The drivers shipped with the device included the full widcomm bluetooth package, which it seems most manufacturers provide. [Manufacturer's Drivers for Vista/Win7 32/64][1]

Downloaded the Bluetooth Driver installer from Broadcom's website, had to use google cache, website seemed to be down. [Broadcom Download](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php), and [Google Cache][3].

It's a small download, it downloads another installer to actually do the work. But now that it's installed, the native windows 7 bluetooth support for my stereo headphones (A2DP device) and cellphone (calls/audio) are working great.

Link1: www.iogear.com/support/driver/BT_VISTA_7_v6.2.1.500.zip Link3: webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0SrsQE0iqQwJ:www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php+http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: I've been seeing HIDDATA crashes for a while now because of this, they seem to be harmless, all the bluetooth pairings/devices continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

eHow: [How to Use a Bluetooth Headset With a Computer](http://www.ehow.com/how_4793407_use-bluetooth-headset-computer.html)
TomsHardware discussion on [Bluetooth headset & Laptop](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/29559-35-bluetooth-headset-laptop)

You may want to confirm the adapter capabilities for your headset usage,
This is just [a quick adapter link](http://www.buy.com/prod/aluratek-abd2020-usb-2-0-hi-speed-bluetooth-edr-adapter-aluratek/q/loc/101/203469315.html) for reference (not a suggestion to purchase this one).

Answer (score 1):

I've searched, and as far as I can see there were never any drivers released for i.Tech Arrow II, or at least on Internet.

If you have received any driver cd for vista, you can use vista drivers in win7 (although none exists on google). If not, then you're totally dependent on Win7, so if it fails to find the drivers, then there's probably no good solution.

However, if you can find a vista machine on which this works, you can extract the driver by using [Driver Magician Lite](http://www.drivermagician.com/Lite.htm), and transfer it to win7.